# IP WHOIS request via PHP fails only at whois.lacnic.net

Tags: php, curl, whois

I have a simple PHP script which fetches IP WHOIS info from an external server curing cURL.

In it's basic form:

```
$ip = "11.22.33.44";
$whois_server = "whois.ripe.net";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $whois_server.":43"); // Whois Server
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "$ip\r\n"); // Query
$whois = curl_exec ($ch);  

echo "RESULT: ".$whois;
echo "<br/>";
echo curl_errno ($ch);
echo "<br/>";
```

Now this works great on server: `whois.ripe.net`, also on `whois.arin.net` and on `whois.apnic.net`.

But when I query `whois.lacnic.net`, it shows the following error:

```
% No match for "IPADDRESSHERE
 / HTTP/1.1
HOST: WHOIS.LACNIC.NET:43
ACCEPT:"
```

I know `whois.lacnic.net` works, because I can query that fine via another script using `fsockopen`. But I need it to work via cURL.

I think that server doesn't like the `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` I give it. But I have no clue how else to form it.

Comment: Probably you have to specify `CURLPROTO_TELNET` in `CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS`. However, `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` is not accepted in this case and PHP cURL implementation lacks function to send raw data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to add: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_TELNET); but then cURL returns nothing. No errors either. Anything else I can try?

Comment: just a little bump :))

Comment: Why exactly are you using an HTTP library to connect to a protocol (`whois`) not running over HTTP? You have specific libraries in PHP to handle `whois` or otherwise just open a socket on port 43 and that is enough. You will only get problems by using the wrong tool for your specific case.